# Upload zip from local in azure blob subcontainer

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, blob, azure-blob-storage

I’m using azure function with **node js** to create a zip file(abc.zip) with some files in function app temp folder and on the next step I need to upload the zip file in azure blob storage. Problem is the blob storage path has to be something like ‘/**xyz/pqr/ghk**’. How to achieve this?

Comment: Just prepend the folder path to the blob name. For example, if you want to upload `abc.zip` in `xyz/pqr` folder, just change the name of the blob to `xyz/pqr/abc.zip`.

Comment: in azure blob storage the folder structure is virtual so you can give path as you want . Eg /xyz/pqr/ghk/test.zip => will create folder inside a folder and then it will add test.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GauravMantri indicated,Try this :

```
const {
    BlobServiceClient
  } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

  const connectionString = ''
  const container = ''
  const destBlobName = 'test.zip'
  const blob = 'xyz/pqr/ghk/' + destBlobName

  const zipFilePath = "<some function temp path>/<filename>.zip"

  const blobClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString).getContainerClient(container).getBlockBlobClient(blob)
  blobClient.uploadFile(zipFilePath)
```

Result:
[image]

Let me know if you have any more questions :)

Comment: Thanks @StanleyGong for the code snippets...it helped..